# POP3 disconnect not working

Tags: delphi, indy, pop3

I'm having trouble with POP3 Client in delphi (indy). I can use some functionality only once after connecting to a POP3Server - the first time i type :

POP3Client.Connect

(with username, password, etc..) everything is just fine.But the second time I get message 'Already connected' and nothing like checkmessages, retrieveHeader, retrieve works.And if I try

POP3Client.Disconnect

it gives me an error 'Connection closed gracefully'. Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Disconnect()` sends a `QUIT` command to the server by default, which will fail if the connection has already been lost. If you are calling `Disconnect()` after a previous socket error occurred, pass false to the `ANotifyPeer` parameter of `Disconnect()` to bypass the QUIT command:

```
POP3Client.Disconnect(false);
```

Do note that bypassing the `QUIT` prevents the server from entering the **UPDATE** state, so if you had previously called `Delete()` then those messages will not be removed from the server, as deletion only occurrs during the UPDATE state.  Use `ANotifyPeer=false` only during error handling, use `ANotifyPeer=true` during normal operation.